# ML Kit Firebase textDetection does not detect clearly

Tags: java, android, android-camera, firebase-mlkit

The project that show in textView after taked photo from camera. Using Firebase ML kit for text detection. That's not detect text clearly. It detect some of words but not detect all clearly. Using bitmap for it I don't if this bitmap make this problem. Should I use SurfaceView for camera? Or whats solution to solve that?

[image]

activity_main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cameraButton"
        android:layout_width="108dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="44dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_camera_alt_24"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.427" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/detectButton"
        android:layout_width="108dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="44dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="41dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_done_outline_24"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.445" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mImageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="346dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_image_24" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/segoeui"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mImageView" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView mImageView;
    ImageButton cameraBtn;
    ImageButton detectBtn;
    Bitmap imageBitmap;
    TextView textView;
    String log = "error";
    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mImageView = findViewById(R.id.mImageView);
        cameraBtn = findViewById(R.id.cameraButton);
        detectBtn = findViewById(R.id.detectButton);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setTypeface(ResourcesCompat.getFont(this, R.font.segoeui));

        cameraBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dispatchTakePictureIntent();
                textView.setText("");
            }
        });
        detectBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                detectTextFromImage();

            }
        });
    }


    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!= null) {
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
              Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
              imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
              mImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
        }
    }

    private void detectTextFromImage() {
        FirebaseVisionImage firebaseVisionImage = FirebaseVisionImage.fromBitmap(imageBitmap);
        FirebaseVisionCloudTextRecognizerOptions options = new FirebaseVisionCloudTextRecognizerOptions.Builder()
                .setLanguageHints(Arrays.asList("eng","hi"))
                .build();
        FirebaseVisionTextRecognizer detector = FirebaseVision.getInstance()
                .getCloudTextRecognizer(options);
        Task<FirebaseVisionText> result =
                detector.processImage(firebaseVisionImage)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FirebaseVisionText>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(FirebaseVisionText firebaseVisionText) {
                                // Task completed successfully
                                // ...
                                displayTextFromImage(firebaseVisionText);
                            }
                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(
                                new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                        // Task failed with an exception
                                    }
                                });

    }

    private void displayTextFromImage(FirebaseVisionText firebaseVisionText) {
        List<FirebaseVisionText.TextBlock> blockList = firebaseVisionText.getTextBlocks();
        if (blockList.size() == 0){
            Toast.makeText(this,"No Text Found in image!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            for (FirebaseVisionText.TextBlock block: firebaseVisionText.getTextBlocks()) {
                String text = block.getText();
                textView.setText(text);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a sample photo containing the text and a screenshot of the text recognition result?

Comment: @DongChen https://ibb.co/1fcs9BJ

Answer (score 0):

There's a sample app of text recognition on both iOS and Android platform at https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/samples (vision quickstart), and seems like both can detect the text within given image successfully?

Answer (score 0):

`private void displayTextFromImage(FirebaseVisionText firebaseVisionText) { List<FirebaseVisionText.TextBlock> blockList = firebaseVisionText.getTextBlocks(); if (blockList.size() == 0){ Toast.makeText(this,"No Text Found in image!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); } else{ String text = ""; for (FirebaseVisionText.TextBlock block: firebaseVisionText.getTextBlocks()) { text = text + "\n" + block.getText(); textView.setText(text); } } }`

By declaring and initializing String text inside for loop, will cause you lost the text of previous block. Actually, it takes each line as one block. Loop executes so fast, then you see only last line or last block of text set as your textview. Replace that code with this one, to resolve that issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).